# API Rewrites are not working. Must use api.php?type=rest/products rather than api/rest/products

Tags: magento-enterprise, api, url-rewrite

I'm having trouble getting Magento to use the rewritten API URL. My Apache configuration for the site is:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/site.com/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My .htaccess for the site is:

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|stage|dev)\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://dev.site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
############################################
## default index file
    DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_flag session.auto_start off
    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
     <FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|flv|pdf)$">
          Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400"
     </FilesMatch>
     <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf|woff)$">
         Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
     </FilesMatch>
     <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|txt)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400"
     </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl|asp|html)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
    AddDefaultCharset Off
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
```

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the redirect stuff for the api.
There should be something like

```
# uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
```

in your .htaccess

Comment: Sorry, I had stripped all comments before posting my htaccess. The issue seems to have been where this code was located. I had this rule (`RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]` at the end of my file where it should have been directly under `#RewriteBase /magento/`

Answer (score 1):

If the default Magento htaccess has been modified ensure that `RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]` is directly beneath `#RewriteBase /magento/`